# Show that $k = 3$ is the only integer solution for $\sqrt{2^k+1 }$ to be rational

Tags: number-theory

The question is easy to verify but hard to prove. Can anyone suggest some idea? I have one approach using Pell's equation, but I don't quite get it .

Comment: What is the difference between proving and verifying?

Comment: It seems this follows from Catalan's conjecture (now Mihăilescu's theorem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First assume $k>0$.  Suppose that
$$2^k+1=\Bigl(\frac xy\Bigr)^2$$
where $x,y$ are positive integers which, without loss of generality, have no common factor.  We have
$$y^2(2^k+1)=x^2\ ;$$
this means that any prime factor of $y$ is also a factor of $x$, and hence $y$ cannot have any prime factors.  That is, $y=1$.  Therefore
$$2^k=x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$$
and so $x-1$ and $x+1$ are both powers of $2$.  The only powers of $2$ differing by $2$ are $2^1$ and $2^2$, so $x=3$ and $k=3$.

If $k<0$, say $k=-m$, we have
$$y^2(1+2^m)=x^22^m\ .$$
As before, $y$ has no odd prime factor, and by unique factorisation $y^2=2^m$, so $m$ is even.  But then we have $1+2^m=x^2$ and the above argument gives $m=3$.  So there is no solution for $k<0$.

Trivially, $k=0$ is not a solution.